# PXUIRequired BQL statement

Tags: acumatica

Page: AR303000
I need to change my BQL statement from a where to a where2.
My end goal is that if the customerClassID is 02 or 03 that the Attention field becomes Required

Below is the Where2 that needs to be fixed:

```
[PXUIRequired(typeof(Where2<Where
<Customer.customerClassID, Equal<attentionRequiredCustomerClass02>>, Or<Customer.customerClassID, Equal<attentionRequiredCustomerClass03>>>))]
```

This is the code snippet:

```
    //create constant class to check the CustomerClassID that is a string
    public const string AttentionRequiredCustomerClass02 = "02";
    public class attentionRequiredCustomerClass02 : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Constant<attentionRequiredCustomerClass02>
    {
        public attentionRequiredCustomerClass02() : base(AttentionRequiredCustomerClass02) {; }
    }

    //create constant class to check the CustomerClassID that is a string
    public const string AttentionRequiredCustomerClass03 = "03";
    public class attentionRequiredCustomerClass03 : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Constant<attentionRequiredCustomerClass03>
    {
        public attentionRequiredCustomerClass03() : base(AttentionRequiredCustomerClass03) {; }
    }



    //Contact.Attention
    //merge the attribute with the existing, setting the making Attention required when CustomerClassID = 2
    [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Merge)]
    [PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    //selector follows the contact's baccount to get the customer class, and compares it to the bql constant created above.
    //[PXUIRequired(typeof(Where2<Where<Customer.customerClassID, Equal<attentionRequiredCustomerClass02>>, Or<Customer.customerClassID, Equal<attentionRequiredCustomerClass03>>>))]
    [PXUIRequired(typeof(Where<Selector <Contact.bAccountID,Customer.customerClassID>, Equal<attentionRequiredCustomerClass02>>))]
    protected virtual void Contact_Attention_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
    { }
```

The [PXUIRequired] that is not commented out is working I need to incorporate the attentionRequiredCustomerClass03 into my statement.

My end goal is that if the customerClassID is 02 or 03 that the Attention field becomes Required

Comment: Please provide more details: what error are you receiving? What are you looking to do?

Comment: I think i am using the where2 incorrectly because the PXUIRequired is not working when I use Where2 but is working with the normal where.
I am looking to change the where to a where2 so that I can see if the customerClassID is 02 or 03

Comment: are you currently receiving an error? or is the data not being filtered (as if the PXUIRequired would not be there)?

Comment: There is no error, it is as if there is no PXUIRequied. My end goal is that if the customerClassID is 02 or 03 that the Attention field becomes Required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PXUIRequired approach was not working on my end either.

This other approach worked correctly during the **creation** of new Customers:

```
protected virtual void Contact_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Row == null)
            return;

        Customer row = this.Base.CurrentCustomer.Current; 
         PXDefaultAttribute.SetPersistingCheck<Contact.attention>(sender, e.Row, row.CustomerClassID == "02" || row.CustomerClassID == "03" ? PXPersistingCheck.NullOrBlank : PXPersistingCheck.Nothing);
 }


[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Merge)]
[PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
protected virtual void Contact_Attention_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
{ }
```

[image]

[image]

Be aware that for existing records, if the custom class was changed, the validation was not enforced unless any other field from the Contact form was changed. Most likely because the cache is not modified therefore its corresponding events are not executed.